# Initialize subclass by first sending a 2D-array to the super class in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, multidimensional-array, int

I'm trying to code the following Java code in C++:

```java
public class Block {
    private int[][] block;
    public Block(int[][] block) {
        this.block = block;
    }
}

public class Block1 extends Block {
    public Block1() {
        super(new int[][]{{2,3},{3,1}});
    }
}
```

Below you can see how far I have come with my translation of the code to C++. Basically I want Block to be a general class which helps the inheriting classes (currently only Block1) to store data about them as 2D arrays. These arrays should be initialized right in the subclasses' contructor's.
But I can't get the super call to work correctly in Block1, neither do I know how I should send a 2D array as a parameter, or how to correctly store the reference to it again. It would be awesome if you guys could show me this.

(I will add more methods later to the classes - this is only the most essential stuff related to the problem.)

**Block.h:**

```c
#ifndef BLOCK_H_
#define BLOCK_H_

namespace mtch {

class Block {
public:
    Block(int _block[][2]);
    virtual ~Block();
private:
    int block[2][2];
};

} /* namespace mtch */
#endif /* BLOCK_H_ */
```

**Block.cpp:**

```c
#include "Block.h"

namespace mtch {

Block::Block(int _block[][2]) {
    block = _block;
}

} /* namespace mtch */
```

**Block1.h:**

```c
#include "Block.h"

#ifndef BLOCK1_H_
#define BLOCK1_H_

namespace mtch {

class Block1 : public Block {
public:
    Block1();
    virtual ~Block1();
};

} /* namespace mtch */
#endif /* BLOCK1_H_ */
```

**Block1.cpp:**

```c
#include "Block1.h"

namespace mtch {

Block1::Block1() : Block(new int[][]{{2,2},{2,3}}) {
}

}
```

I hope you understand what I'm trying to accomplish here. :P

Answer (score 0):

block is a static array as you defined it, you can't simply assign a dynamic array to it to bend pointers to the right memory location. You would have to copy each element into block. Easiest way would be to use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead of int[2][2] for block. Another way would be to use a simple one dimensional array everywhere. you'd make block of type int* and make all the functions take int* too. Then you can just new int[4] in Block1() and initialize the memory inside Block1()'s body. Also you would have to make sure to delete[] the memory because it won't happen automagically like it does for the static array. Multidimensional arrays are a bit [icky](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.16)